# How can I get the element of a-tag in the div class with selenium?

Tags: html, ruby, selenium

I recently work on the project that I have to get the element from a specific website.

I want to get the text elements that are something below.

```
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="block-heading">
    <a href="https://www~~~~~~">  
      <i class="fa fa-map">
        ::before
      </i>
       "Text I want to get"
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to solve this for a while, but I could not find anything working fine.

I would love you if you could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Which node you have to locate? `a`?  And Text I want to get really surround by double quote as shown above? and `::before` really comes inside the `i` tag? Can you confirm me?

Comment: Thank you for asking me. To make it precise, it really is surrounded by double quote and ::before is inside the i tag.  it looks like i tag just has an icon.
This time, I need to get the text.  "Text I want to get" above.

Comment: @Abel did you try my solution?

Comment: Okay. Which element you would like to locate?Your goal is to extract the sting "Text I want to get"?

Comment: @Eliyahu
I have been working on it. 
I tried to get the text with this xpath that  I found in the page first, but it didn't work.
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a/text()")

Comment: First of all: never, really, never use absolute `xpath` until you have to do it. I had never face such situation during all the years I'm coding automation.

Comment: I see. That was my bad that I tried it with the hope to solve it easily.

Comment: I have written an answer for you which would uses the regular expression which will return the text you would like to see. Try it and let me know whether it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the elements that I wanted directly, so here's what I did.
It is just that I did modify the elements with some methods though.

```
  def seller_name
    shop_info_elements = @driver.find_elements(:class_name, "block-content")
    shop_info_text= shop_info_elements.first.text
    shop_info_text_array = shop_info_text.lines
    seller_name = shop_info_text_array.first.chomp
    seller_name
  end
```

It is not beautiful, but it can work for any other pages on the same site.

Answer (score 1):

According to the information you provided the text you are looking for is inside `a` element so the `xpath` for this element is something like:
`//a[contains(@href,'https://www')]`
But since there is also `i` element inside it, getting the text from `a` element will give you both text contained in `a` itself and the text inside the `i`.
So you should get the text from `i` that is looking like just a   (space) here and reduce it from the text you are receiving from the `a`.
In case you want to perform this action on all the `a` elements containing `href` and `i` element inside it you can use the following `xpath`:
`//a[@href and ./i]`
If there are more specific definitions about  the elements you are looking for - the `xpath` I mentioned should be updated accordingly

Comment: thank you.
Unfortunately I am going to get the element that is located here in many pages, which means I can't select specific URL with XPATH. 
Does it mean I can't do things you mentioned ?

Comment: In case that element has some common unique attribute or the same relative position related to some other, permanent element you can use it each time that element appears. Otherwise it's not the same element and you have to find / define it each time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
apparently it looks like there is nothing exact the same structure as the one I mentioned above, which I mean the one nested in the block-heading in the block-content. So I can take it as unique I hope.

Comment: Without seeing the site you are working with I can't see if there some generic approach there.
I did my best to help you according to the information you provided.

Comment: Thank you anyways. I thought it is not allowed to paste the URL of the specific site here.
the site is below and the text is the middle part and says CARS in this site.
https://www.truck-bank.net/modules/truck/index.php?action=DataView&data_id=196767

Comment: @Abel I updated the answer accordingly to the new information you provided. Generally, when asking questions on SO you should provide as much as possible relevant information to get the correct answer.

Comment: @Abel please accept or/and upvote my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I understood that you would like to extract that text. So here is the code for you which would extract the text you want.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Wait
  .new(timeout: 60)
  .until { !driver.find_element(xpath: "//i[@class='fa fa-map-marker']/..").text.empty? }

p driver.find_element(xpath: "//i[@class='fa fa-map-marker']/..").text[/(?<=before \")\w+ \w+ \w+ \w+ \w+/]
```

output

```
"Text I want to get"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, since I have been working on this for a week, meeting someone like you make me feel supported.
Unfortunately I couldn't get the text with the code you gave me, I got some elements with just this though. find_element(xpath: "//i[@class='fa fa-map']/..").
with fallowing code you wrote, I got nothing.
Only change I might have to let you know is the name of the class is more precisely this "fa fa-map-marker".
But I guess that doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @Abel `i` with class name precisely `fa fa-map-marker` gives exactly one element and not a list of elements as you mentioned before

Comment: @Abel Empty string is being printed?

Comment: @Rajagopalan
yes... I am sorry that even though you told me a lot I couldn't solve it.
and nothing comes as result...

Comment: @Abel Don't worry, that's expected because program executes even before that tag loads properly. I have updated the code. Try now. It would work.

Comment: @Rajagopalan
thank you. I  am afraid when it crawls it has to take a timeout in my code and the elements are not written with JS so I thought the timeout doesn't really matter.
this is the site and the word that says CARS is the exact text I want to get this time.
https://www.truck-bank.net/modules/truck/index.php?action=DataView&data_id=196767